# What is the solution for a many entries in listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to Android development. I have around 500 entries in my list view, with every click opens local html file. 
Do I have to encode all the switch statements manually? 
Can I match the index of the item on the list for it to open the corresponding html file? 
Thanks!

Comment: You really want your users to scroll through 500 entries to find what they are looking for? Why don't you just put it in some type of hierarchy

Comment: How did you open the html file? Include the code.

Comment: @iturki wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test2.html");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name the html files with numbers in the name, you can match those numbers with the position in the list. Like, htmlfile001.html would be in position 1. Then the getView in your listAdapter assembles the name from the position, and shows the filename, and the onclick sends the file name to the viewer, in the intent.